# Class.forName() is not able find classpath of other project file

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, classloader

I have created a plugin to fetch the fields of a particular .java file for that I am using following code:

```
Class<?> forName = Class.forName(refPath);//refPath = "xyz.test"
Field[] declaredFields = forName.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : declaredFields) {
    String name = field.getName();
}
```

When I deployed this plugin in to the workspace, it is perfectly working for its plugin project but not fetching fields for other project of same workspace. throwing exception ClassNotFound, obviously classloader is not able to find other projects file.

Is there any way i can get the file information for other projects(plugin/non plugin)of same workspace where plugin is deployed?

Comment: You have to add the other plugins/projects/JARs as dependencies in the CLASSPATH.  That's the only way the JVM will find the .class files it needs.

Comment: The Eclipse [JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) will give you lots of details about classes in the workspace.

Comment: In order to load the class that is managed by another plugin, you need to ask the other plugins classloader for that class. If your plugin depends on the other plugin, you can use its classloader (this.getClass().get lassLoader()). Otherwise you need to obtain the other plugins classloader.

Comment: BTW `Class.forName` (ass well as `ClassLoader::load`) require the fully qualified name of a class, not a path. 'xyz.test' in your example certainly isn't a valid class name.

Answer (score 0):

AS stated in the comment, you need the java class containers (JAR?) to be in your classpath.

Whether you can do it statically, and add the other archive to your classpath when starting your JVM, Or you can try to add it dynamicaly.

To do it, here is what you can do :

```
/**
 * Adds a jar file dynamically to the current class path
 * @param jarFile
 */
private static void addToClassPath(File jarFile) {
    try {
        System.out.println("adding " + jarFile.getAbsolutePath() + " to classpath");
        URL u = jarFile.toURI().toURL();
        URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        /* Here is a trick to call URLClassLoader.addURL whereas this method is 'protected' */
        Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
        Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", sysClassLoaderParams);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[] { u });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while updating classpath: "+ e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello its not working, situation is that from plugin project I am not able access other project's (plugin or non plugin) in same workspace. then I after I have to find out the all field list which are not annotated.